# Warning message when I run the plm function for fixed effects

Tags: r, regression, warnings, plm

I don't understand what's happening in RStudio. After running the `plm` function for fixed effects estimators, I get a warning that appears for whatever I type in R. The warning is

`In if (n >= 10000L) return(TRUE) : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

For instance, consider

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(wooldridge)
library(plm)
data=wagepan
fixed_effects_model=plm(lwage~d81+d82+d83+d84+d85+d86+d87+married+union+ I(d81*educ)+I(d82*educ)+I(d83*educ)+I(d84*educ)+I(d85*educ)+I(d86*educ)+I(d87*educ),index="nr",model="within",data=data)
summary(fixed_effects_model)
```

From the `summary` function onward, I consistently receive the warning message mentioned above.

Comment: I can't replicate the warning message (R 4.3.1, plm 2.6-3, macOS Ventura).  The message comes from the fact that however `n` is calculated internally returns a vector of length greater than 1 and `if()` is saying that it's only evaluating the condition for the first element of `n`.

Comment: Maybe check that all your libraries are up-to-date?

Comment: Issue solved! I needed to update R.